# Multiple Hyperlink click of textview Android

Tags: android

I have a string in my database as below

```
Sring a = "Victory to the <a href='word1'>GOD<\/a>, renowned in <a href='word2'>all three worlds!<\/a>";
text1.setText(Html.fromHtml(a));
```

Now I need the hyperlink id (`word1` and `word2`) of both `link` that will help to set another textView property. Can anybody tell me how can i do that? or any other approach to achieve this?

Comment: What are you meaning by "id of word1 and word2" ? How about stocking the string link in an HashMap and build your a dynamically ?

Comment: could you please review edited.? My goal is that String word1 shows as hyperlink in textview and while user click on that text(word1) it will set to another textview.

Comment: Are you controlling the href string ? And what about doing it with button or separated TextView for each your href ?

Comment: yes you can see it. I am assigning it with text1.setText(Html.fromHtml(a)); and I want click of every hyperlink of textview.

Comment: Yeah I see that, what I mean is are you controlling the String a source and precisally the "<a href='word1'>", how do you retrieve this string ?

Comment: I have all the <a href=""> strings to my db and I am fetching it from there. What i need is identify other string from that 'word1'. is it possible to get word1 after setting it to textview ?. Where i can setListener for implement click of that hyperlinks?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24570/discussion-between-plumillon-forge-and-a4android)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had achieve this using Webview instead of textview and created custom webview client to over ride url.

```
webview1.setWebViewClient(new myWebViewClient());
webview1.loadData(myHTMLStringWithHyperlinks, "text/html", "UTF-8");

private class myWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

            Log.i(TAG, "Id of hyperlink text is: "+url);

            }

            return true;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

use SubString-method to identifie your ID's search for the position of **href='**. Make a temp variable that now contains the Substring:

```
"word1'>GOD<\/a>, renowned in <a href='word2'>all three worlds!<\/a>"
```

then search for the position of **'** the SubString from the temp-vars frist character until the position of **'** is contains your ID

next you put this SubString to in the temp-var:

```
>GOD<\/a>, renowned in <a href='word2'>all three worlds!<\/a>"
```

now you can repeat the previous steps to receive the second ID

Comment: could you please review it again?

Answer (score 0):

Oki here are my 2 solutions which come to my mind at the moment :

**1. Implements your own schema :**

You need first to replace all the `http://` (or `https//`, well the URL schema you catch the thing) with your custom schema `customSchema://` :

```
a.replaceAll("[\\"\']{1}[a-zA-Z]+:\/\/[\\"\']{1}", "customSchema://");
```

(I'm not sure about my regular expression, I just write it here)

Then you declare your Activity can handle this kind of schema in your AndroidManifest.xml :

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="customSchema" />
</intent-filter>
```

At this moment your Activity will be launched for every customSchema://... URL that is clicked (even in others applications)

You just have to retrieve the URL on your Activity and do what you want with it :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

  setContentView(R.layout.main);

  // Get the intent that started this activity
  Intent intent = getIntent();
  Uri data = intent.getData();
}
```

And in case it's your Activity which launch the click, refer to [onNewIntent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent%28android.content.Intent%29)

**2. The second solution is this easiest in my opinion :**

You split your String into separate one, the goal is to isolate the "word1", "word2" in different TextView, like that :

```
<TextView 1 (Victory to the) /><TexTview 2 (word1 GOD) /><TextView 3 (renowned in) /><TextView 4 (word2 all three worlds) />
```

You can easily do that with Regular Expression

You can set the word1 and word2 to the TextView 2 and TextView 4 in the tag (`setTag()`) to retrieve it later

Register a onClick event on your TextView 2 and TextView 4 and do what you want in those (here you get your tag (`getTag()`)